# Error en media aritmética

Tags: python

Estoy programando un ejercicio en Python 3.7 que hace la media aritmética de unos valores introducidos, pero sin usar las funciones sum() y mean(), únicamente con un bucle for. El código:

```
    def mAritmetica (valores):
    """tupla(float) -> float
    OBJ: Media aritmetica de valores introducidos
    PRE: valores = valores numéricos"""
    sumatorio=0 # El sum inicial debe ser 0 ya que se trata de un bucle for
    for valor in valores:
        sumatorio=sumatorio+valor # sumamos un número n al anterior cada vez que se repite el bucle
        return sumatorio/len(valores)
# PROBADOR
print (mAritmetica(4,7,3,6))
```

El caso es que continuamente me devuelve este error:

> Exception has occurred: TypeError
>   mAritmetica() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given
>     File "U:\1º\Fundamentos Programación\bibliotecaEstadística.py", line 11, in 
>       print (mAritmetica(4,7,3,6))

Muchas gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda! :)

Answer (score 2):

EL problema es que tienes que meter todos los valores dentro de un arreglo, []. Ya que tu función solo recibe un argumento y en principio le estás enviando más de uno, si insertas todo en un solo arreglo siempre estarás enviando un parámetro y con eso te servirá, lo otro es que tu sentencia de retorno se ejecutaba en la primera iteración del ciclo y deberá ejecutarse justo después del ciclo porque sino el resultado siempre será el primer valor entre la cantidad de elementos.

Una recomendación extra es que no utilices tildes dentro de tu código, lastimosamente esto puede generar errores.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
def mAritmetica (valores):
  """tupla(float) -> float
  OBJ: Media aritmetica de valores introducidos
  PRE: valores = valores numericos"""
  sumatorio=0 # El sum inicial debe ser 0 ya que se trata de un bucle for
  for valor in valores:
    sumatorio=sumatorio+valor # sumamos un numero n al anterior cada vez que se repite el bucle
  return sumatorio/len(valores)
# PROBADOR
print (mAritmetica([4,7,3,6]))
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero un detalle. Las tildes ya no deberían producir ningún problema en Python3, siempre que el editor en que escribas el código lo guarde en UTF-8. Y si lo guardas en otro encoding (no deberías, utf-8 es el estándar hoy día), siempre puedes añadir al inicio del script el comentario `# coding: latin1` por ejemplo, o el encoding que haya usado tu editor. ¡No renunciemos a poner tildes o eñes donde sea necesario! (aunque en según qué contextos puede ser mejor escribir documentación y comentarios en inglés)

Comment: También es posible enviar un número variable de argumentos como está planteado en la pregunta. Bastaría con poner un `*` delante de la lista que recoge los valores. En cuanto a los tipos de datos, mejor usar los _type hints_ estándar, algo así `def mAritmetica(*valores: float) -> float`.